# Pandas - divide each row by a group average

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying so solve a somewhat simple task but it is not clear how to achieve it in pandas.

So I have a pandas dataframe which has a set of columns I am interested in. Set of columns is stored in `factors` list:

```
#get df
df = pd.read_sql(sql=sqlString, con = engine)

#shuffle
df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=123).reset_index(drop=True)

#list of fields we want
factors = ['GRP_RANK', 'BK_YIELD', 'SALES_YIELD', 'EARNINGS_YIELD_LTM', 'CASHFLOW_YIELD', 'ROE', 'ROIC',
           'ROA', 'GROSS_MGN', '12MVT', '1MVT', 'BETA_3Y', 'BETA_1Y', 'P_TOTAL_RETURN(-1,0,USD)']
```

Now, there is column `DATE` in dataframe. For each of the `factors` for each record I want to divide the value of factor by the average of the factor value on particular date.

I managed to obtain the averages by day for each factor:

```
dfGroup = df[factors + ["DATE"]].groupby('DATE')[factors].mean()
```

But I am not sure how to proceed. Only thing which comes to my mind is get new big dataframe by left joining `df` and `dfGroup` by DATE field and then doing some ugle column by column division, but maybe there is a way to do it easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at using `groupby` and `transform` with `div`:

MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2018-02-10','2018-02-12',freq='H'),'A':np.random.randint(0,100,49),'B':np.random.randint(100,200,49),'C':np.random.random(49)})

df = df.set_index('Date')

print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
                      A    B         C
Date                                  
2018-02-10 00:00:00  11  131  0.474226
2018-02-10 01:00:00  35  188  0.998742
2018-02-10 02:00:00  97  182  0.683685
2018-02-10 03:00:00   0  134  0.845094
2018-02-10 04:00:00  24  173  0.238379
```

Use groupby, transfrom and div:

```
df[['A','B','C']].div(df.groupby(df.index.floor('D')).transform('mean'))
```

Output head():

```
                        A         B         C
Date                                             
2018-02-10 00:00:00  0.362637  0.866593  0.931739
2018-02-10 01:00:00  1.153846  1.243660  1.962284
2018-02-10 02:00:00  3.197802  1.203969  1.343275
2018-02-10 03:00:00  0.000000  0.886439  1.660404
2018-02-10 04:00:00  0.791209  1.144432  0.468357
```